# Using my own object as key in a TreeMap

Tags: java, collections, concurrency, treemap, sortedmap

As TreeMap sorting is based only on the keys, I'm using a custom object as key in a treemap. I have respected in my opinion the contract between equals and compareTo in this case, if the two objects are equal, te compareTo returns 0.

Below the code of the object:

```
public final class UserHighScore implements Comparable<UserHighScore>{

private final int userId;
private final int value;


public UserHighScore(int userId, int value) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.value = value;
}

public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == this) return true;
    if (!(obj instanceof UserHighScore)) {
        return false;
    }
    UserHighScore userHighScore = (UserHighScore) obj;
    return userHighScore.userId==userId;
}


@Override
public int compareTo(UserHighScore uh) {
    if(uh.getUserId()==this.getUserId()) return 0;
    if(uh.getValue()>this.getValue()) return 1;
    return -1;
}
```

}

And below the method that is causing the problem:

If the user id's are the same I want to return 0 to avoid duplication, so then if I do map.put(userHighscore) it should automatically replace is there is another object in the map with the same userId.
However if the users are diferent, I want them to be sorted according the their values.
This approach is working perfectly fine for one thread, however my app is concurrent and when there are more than a threas, it is adding duplicates to the map. 
My problem is with the highscores map, which is a concurrentHasmap and inside it contains a treemap.

DO you see anything wrong with my approach?

Comment: If you use more than one thread, what is your synchronization strategie?

Comment: You might want to use a map from the concurrent package https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/collections.html

Comment: Already doing that. I have edited the question to show the code, I'm using concurrentHashmap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Looking better at the source of `TreeMap` `hashCode` is not a real problem.

The problem is here

```
if (highScores.get(levelId)==null) {
    highScores.put(levelId,Collections.synchronizedSortedMap(new TreeMap<UserHighScore,Integer>()));
}
```

This code is not thread safe also if `highScores` is a `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Here a possible scenario

```
Thread 1                                    Thread 2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
highScores.get(levelId) is null
                                            highScores.get(levelId) is null
highScores.put(levelId, ...);
                                            highScores.put(levelId, ...);
```

From here the two threads use a different instance of `SynchronizedSortedMap`.

---

**Previous answer**

`TreeMap` is not a synchronized version of `Map`.

If you work in a multithreading environment you need to synchronize the access to the `TreeMap`.

```
TreeMap<UserHighScore> myTree = ...
...
UserHighScore userHighScore = ...
...
synchronized(myTree) {
    // Synchronize any access to myTree
    myTree.add(userHighScore);
}
```

But you need also to redefine the [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) method because you are using a `Map`:

> Returns a hash code value for the object. This method is supported for the benefit of hash tables such as those provided by HashMap.

Remember to redefine the `hashCode` following the contract:

> - Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.
> - If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.
> - It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.

Comment: I thought hashCode redefinition was only required for HashMaps and sets

Comment: But treeMap uses compareTo for equality instead of hashCode, I should anyway redefine hashcode then?

Comment: @fgonzalez I edited my answer, as you said is not a real problem here the hashCode function.

Answer (score 0):

In your POJO object over ride hashcode to :

```
public int hashCode(){
    return  (userId + "").hashCode()
```

You could also cache the hash code.

```
private final int userId;
private final int userIdHash;
...


public UserHighScore(int userId, int value) {
    this.userId = userId;
    userIdHash = (userId + "").hashCode();
...

public int hashCode(){
    return userIdHash
```

Test for memory vs hash code calls. But should be fine to cache.

Comment: tgkprog do we really need to override hashcode if we are working on treemap?